# Luanchd not starting mopidy & UDP listener

Tags: bash, udp, launchd, mopidy

I'm trying to write a Launchd script to execute a simple sh script that will 1) launch mopidy 2) mkfifo /tmp/mopidy.fifo 3) pass data from port 5555 into this file using socat.

I've tried setting up a mopidy.plist LaunchAgent that executes a mopidy.sh script file at login. I've verified that the LaunchAgent gets started correctly and that the script has execution permissions. I've also tried the Program Arguments approach by passing the script as a one-liner to /bin/bash, but when I try that I get errors logged saying that its unable to find socat.

mopidy.sh

```sh
nohup mopidy;
mkfifo /tmp/mopidy.fifo;
while :; do 
    socat -d -d -T 1 -u UDP4-LISTEN:5555 OPEN:/tmp/mopidy.fifo; 
done
```

mopidy.plist

```
<!-- Starts mopidy server -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.me.mopidy.plist</string>
    <key>Program</key>
      <string>/Users/me/.config/scripts/mopidy.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/logfile.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/error_logfile.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I am able to execute the bash script normally without error from the command line, however it doesn't seem like the service is able to because the /tmp/modipy.fifo file never gets created and the listener is never made. The logfile and error_logfile are never populated either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by including environment variables. I don't fully understand this, but everything works now with the following:

```sh
<!-- Starts mopidy server -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.me.mopidy.plist</string>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin</string>
    </dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>/Users/me/.config/scripts/mopidy.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/logfile.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/me/error_logfile.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```